# Any way to make swipe up and down work consecutively?

Tags: trackpad, mission-control, gesture

In Mountain Lion I could swipe up with three fingers to see all windows and then swipe down without lifting my fingers to go back to the normal screen.

From Mavericks, that does not work. I have to lift my fingers and then swipe down to go back to the normal screen. This takes more time and inconvenient.

Is there any way to make it work as was in the Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

Try the F3 button (for Exposé). Maybe you'd like the experience better. Now it is two key presses instead of needing to lift your fingers off the trackpad/ keyboard.